# How to get a 100% text extract using OCR?

Tags: ocr

Using the GIT code, we extracted the texts from an image. But found few challenges

1. Few of the characters are being missed during conversion, mostly the missing character is in the start.

   - Example: When the status *`In Progress`* is extracted, only *`n Progress`* is written into the file.
   - If the status is *`Assigned`* it is extracted as *`ssigned`* only
2. There is additional space in the conversion of certain text

   - When the Incident number *`INC123456789`* is extracted, in the file it is written as  *`INC1234 56789`*
3. In some cases, the character itself is changed

   - The sample incident picture had maps with text *`Google`*, when written into the file it was converted as *`GooglA`*

Anyone facing similar issues? And know how to get a 100% text extract?

Comment: No OCR method is 100% reliable. There's no way to say how to improve your particular case because you haven't shown any example images or even told what software you're using.

Comment: I don't think even google can boast about being able to do 100%

Comment: @litelite Yep. In fact, that's the exact idea behind reCAPTCHA - getting humans to do the work where the computer has failed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires a strong AI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to write your own machine learning model, or dare to write your own deep learning neural net.

A simpler option might be to try to map common errors with some sort of dictionary model (simplest example being a Levenshtein Distance model), where:

- You find words that are invalid (*ie. not in the dictionary*). Use levenshtein distances to find the closest word to:

  - Your common lingo expected in the document (*seems like legal words*)
  - Common words in the dictionary (*referred to as **[`bag of words`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)***)
- Replace those words
- A more complicated (*and optional*) approach would be to use ***[`ngram sentence correction`](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/education/EDA171/Reports/2009/david.pdf)*** to correct some group of words (*eg. `n Progress` to `In Progress`*)
- Run a grammatical check to top it off (*best to use an API at this step*)